# Not able to receive a customer header node express

Tags: node.js, express, request-headers, custom-headers

I am working on a NodeJS+Express application. I am not able to receive an incoming header.

I am expecting a header named 'authKey' from another service. But I'm getting undefined when I print this. Refer the code below:

```
const authKey = req.header('auth-key');
console.log(`authKey:${authKey}`);
```

Output:

```
authKey:undefined
```

I tried using npm cors package too, but the result was the same.

Comment: It will come inside request or in middle. It will not seen anywhere else. Try this:

```
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     req.header('auth-key')
   })
```

Comment: Tried this too @ShubhamVerma, didn't work. Is it possible that this particular key is getting blocked by the firewall of my company? Because, there are various other keys like host, user-agent, content-type that are available in the req.headers.

Comment: change `header` to `headers and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to get a header from the request

1. `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));`

this will print all the header key-value present in the request header.

2. `const auth = req.headers['auth-key'];`

else you can use to get a particular header value. The headers are stored in a JavaScript object, with the header strings as object keys.

Comment: I tried both of these but to no avail. Looks like the auth-key header is getting blocked in the firewall of my company maybe.

Comment: can you try sending auth_key as header and try. sometimes ' - ' gets block

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Cross Origin Restrictions that all custom headers by default are blocked. 'authKey' is not defined in the list of safe headers.

**1. Use one of predefined header:**

Refer this for the list of safe headers and their purpose so you can use one of the safe headers to match your purpose.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

**2. Use CORS:**

*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing* allows us to relax the security applied to an API.

```
// nodeJS code
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Read more about why Cross origin restrictions block custom headers [Why does CORS block custom headers by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044886/why-does-cors-block-custom-headers-by-default/45045181)

*it’s not ”CORS” that’s imposing the default restrictions. Instead those restrictions are just part of the default same-origin policy that browsers follow*

Comment: I faced the same issue, where I was sending a custom header and my nodejs application did not pick it up. both option 1 and 2 solved my purpose.